# Scala replace an String with a List of Key/Values

Tags: scala

I have different Strings like this

```
" Hello *|USERNAME|*,

  to activate your account please click here *|ACTIVATION_LINK|*
"
```

another example

```
" Hello,

  to reset your password please click here *|RESET_URL|*
"
```

for the first String I would have a List of key values like this

```
((USERNAME, Nick),(ACTIVATION_URL, http://whateverhost/activation_url))
```

for the second

```
((RESET_URL, http://whateverhost/reset_url))
```

I want to replace the strings with the List of Key/Values, the List can have a variable length and the occurrences of the keys in the String may be multiple

I tried something like this

```
mapKeyValues.map { x => bodyString.replaceAll(x._1, x._2) }
```

But the problem is I get a new List where each row has the replacement of one row of the Key/Values

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Please look at some templating engines, [for example Twirl](https://github.com/playframework/twirl)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do it using foldLeft:

```
mapKeyValues
  .foldLeft (bodyString) {case (acc,(key,value))=>acc.replaceAll(key, value)}
```