# replacing strings inside df using dictionary scala

Tags: scala

I'm new to Scala. Im trying to replace parts of strings using a dictionary.

my dictionary would be:

```
val dict = Seq(("fruits", "apples"),("color", "red"), ("city", "paris")).
 toDF(List("old", "new").toSeq:_*)

+------+------+
|   old|   new|
+------+------+
|fruits|apples|
| color|   red|
|  city| paris|
+------+------+
```

I would then translate fields from a column in another df which is:

```
+--------------------------+
|oldCol                    |
+--------------------------+
|I really like fruits      |
|they are colored brightly |
|i live in city!!          |
+--------------------------+
```

the desired output:

```
+------------------------+
|newCol                  |
+------------------------+
|I really like apples    |
|they are reded brightly |
|i live in paris!!       |
+------------------------+
```

please help! I've tried to covert dict to a map and then use replaceAllIn() function but really can't solve this one.

I've also tried foldleft following this answer: [Scala replace an String with a List of Key/Values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36826290/scala-replace-an-string-with-a-list-of-key-values).
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Create a `Map` from `dict` `dataframe` and then you can easily do this using `udf` like below

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

//Creating Map from dict dataframe

val oldNewMap=dict.map(row=>row.getString(0)->row.getString(1)).collect.toMap

//Creating udf

val replaceUdf=udf((str:String)=>oldNewMap.foldLeft (str) {case (acc,(key,value))=>acc.replaceAll(key+".", value).replaceAll(key, value)})

//Select old column from oldDf and apply udf 

oldDf.withColumn("newCol",replaceUdf(oldDf.col("oldCol"))).drop("oldCol").show

//Output: 
+--------------------+
|              newCol|
+--------------------+
|I really like apples|
|they are reded br...|
|   i live in paris!!|
+--------------------+
```

I hope this will help you

Comment: Thank you so very much! It does work, however, Is it possible to wrap it in an Option[String]? Similarly to other functions in my procees which are: def 
      removeSymbols(s: String): Option[String] ={
             val charactersPattern = "&|-|,|\\.|\\(|\\)".r 
        Option(s).map(charactersPattern.replaceAllIn(_,""))  val udfSymbols = udf[Option[String], String(removeSymbols)   -- I'm sorry it looks so messy!

Comment: Hi again, I have found an inconvenient I don't know how to solve. My map should transform fruits. (with a full stop included) to apples - when a string contains fruits (without the full stop) it will transform to apples too, this would be inconvenient... any ideas?

Comment: Hi @RuthEllie, I modified replaceUdf for your requirements.